# How to check the kubeconfig file through kubectl?

Tags: kubernetes

I'm new in K8s and I need to check the kubeconfig file from a cluster. Is there a way to describe the kubeconfig file using the kubectl?

I'm looking for something similar to `kubectl describe kubeconfig`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can execute the command `kubectl config view` to display merged kubeconfig settings or a specified kubeconfig file.

> By default, kubectl looks for a file named config in the `$HOME/.kube`
> directory. You can specify other kubeconfig files by setting the
> KUBECONFIG environment variable or by setting the `--kubeconfig flag`.

> By default, the kubectl command-line tool uses parameters from the
> `current context` to communicate with the cluster.

Refer to the official document on [Organizing Cluster Access Using kubeconfig Files](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/organize-cluster-access-kubeconfig/) for more information.

The kubeconfig files are merged. To choose the current context use `kubectl config use-context`command. Also see [Kubectl context and configuration](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/kubectl/cheatsheet/#kubectl-context-and-configuration) for more information.

Finally use the `kubectl config -h` command to view further information.